# C# Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api

everyone.

I had written a C# project which reads/writes to the google sheet, and it works fine.
Recently I had replaced my desktop machine, so moved my program into it.
When I started my program, I got the following error.

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.", Uri:""
Source=Google.Apis.Auth
```

I thought its credential maybe be wrong because of my new machine.
So I had created a new credential file by referring to this site
https://www.hardworkingnerd.com/how-to-read-and-write-to-google-sheets-with-c/
(Thank you for your good sharing, Ian)

But I got the same error even with the new credential file.

This is my code:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(new FileStream(credentialFileName, FileMode.Open)).CreateScoped(Scopes);
_sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

...

SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
    _sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(_spreadsheetId, range);
var response = request.Execute(); // Here, I got the error.
```

If I use the OAuth-based credentials (I'm sorry, I don't know its exact terminology) such as https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet,  then it works fine.

Here is my code using OAuth-based credentials.

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
     Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
_sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

...

// Rest codes are same
```

I have been struggling for this error during a half day.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you still have access to the old machine? Can you post your old credentials file? What version of .net are you using on each machine - could it be a problem to do with version? Or dotnetframework vs dotnetcore? You also suggest that on your previous machine you werent using OAuth - are you sure? When was the last time you used your app?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a time issue...

Make sure the clock on your new machine is synced to the correct time.